# "<ID>" Error with a multiple line query SQL in Google App Script using AS statement

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

Multiple line query SQL in Google App script works perfectly like this (I'm querying Big query here) :

```
  var request = {
    query: 
    'SELECT SUM(amount)' +
    'FROM mybigquerytable;'
};
```

However when I'm adding an `AS` statement like this :

```
  var request = {
    query: 
    'SELECT SUM(amount) AS foo' +
    'FROM mybigquerytable;'
};
```

It doesn't work. I have the following error :

`Encountered " <ID> "mybigquerytable "" at line 0, column 0. Was expecting: <EOF> (line 14, file "myscriptnamehere")`

I don't understand why...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add space after foo

```
  var request = {
    query: 
    'SELECT SUM(amount) AS foo ' +
    'FROM mybigquerytable;'
};
```

you can see difference by trying both versions in BigQuery UI:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)FROM mybigquerytable;
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS fooFROM mybigquerytable;
```

Above are equivalent to those in your question and as you will see second will not be able to run